# Why is this font shorthand not working?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I've browsed the other posts on this subject here, and still can't seem to figure this out.  Why is this syntax showing up as invalid and being ignored in Chrome?

```
a, a:active, a:visited {
  font: uppercase 400 1.175em "Lato", sans-serif;
}
```

From the [W3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand)

> The 'font' property is, except as described below, a shorthand property for setting 'font-style', 'font-variant', 'font-weight', 'font-size', 'line-height' and 'font-family' at the same place in the style sheet. The syntax of this property is based on a traditional typographical shorthand notation to set multiple properties related to fonts.

I've tried almost every variation of this I can think of.  I've tried simplifying it down to just 3 properties with no dice.

What's going on?  I'd love to use the shorthand and save a little load time, but I'm starting to think it's a best practice to just avoid it altogether.

UPDATE: The problem was "uppercase".  Can't set 'text-transform' properties in the font: shorthand.  I confused 'font-variant' with 'text-transform'.

Comment: W3Schools is a crappy, error prone tutorial site with massive security holes in some of the code it teaches you to write. It should not be confused with the W3C.

Comment: oh gosh - that's what I get for googling recklessly.  I fixed the quote and link so as not to lead anyone else astray.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote from the W3C doesn't mention `text-transform`.

Remove the `uppercase` from the property and the syntax will be valid.

Comment: and that solved it.  thanks for the quick response.  I confused 'font-variant' with 'text-transform'.

Comment: You're welcome. In this case, the [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) isn't much help, because it gives confusing error messages, but it might help determining that it is indeed an error.